# Stop click function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, click

```
$("button").click(function (){
$("<button>Start</button>).appendTo('main');
});
```

This is my code, Now when I click a button it creates another button. But when I click it again, another button is added. I want to stop adding multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Please add class. You're using a generic selector. So it is the right expected behaviour. Maybe a class like `.clicker` something like that might work.

```js
$("button.clicker").click(function() {
  // Also you're missing a " after </button>
  $("<button>Start</button>").appendTo('main');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <button class="clicker">Click Me</button>
</main>
```